# how to delete multiple instances of a line in a file using python

Tags: python, match, line

I have very large file with the data in the form

```
*Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE 
Part-1-1.SS11, Part-1-1.SS23
*Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE 
Part-1-1.SS7, Part-1-1.SS65 
*Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE 
Part-1-1.SS7, Part-1-1.SS65 
*Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE 
Part-1-1.SS11, Part-1-1.SS23
```

It can be seen that the fields

```
Part-1-1.SS11, Part-1-1.SS23

Part-1-1.SS7, Part-1-1.SS65
```

get repeated in this case. The numbers after SS can change. There are thousand of entries of such line. In each file there can be multiple of such lines with same numbers after SS and only one can remain. Not only the extra instance should be deleted but the above title line should also be deleted along that.

also

```
Part-1-1.SS23,Part-1-1.SS11
```

should be considered the same which is just switching of the fields.

What I tried is

```
for line in infile:
 if line.startswith('Part-1-1.SS'):
  array[line]=line.split(',')
v= array[0]
u= array[1]           
v1,u1 = zip(*sorted(zip(v,u), reverse=True))
counter=len(u)  
for i in xrange(u)
 for j in xrange(v)
  if (u[j]==u[j+1] & v[j]==v[i+1]):
   del u[j]
   del v[]]
```

However, the results are not as desirable as it only deletes the consecutive occurrences and the code is getting too long. Any suggetions?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with a csv reader and some logic to filter out rows in the blacklist. A blacklist made of `frozenset`s will let you avoid having to sort the line before testing for membership in the blacklist

```
import csv

blacklist = set()

with open('path/to/input') as fin, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    infile = csv.reader(fin)
    outfile.csv.writer(fout)
    for title, values in zip(infile, infile):
        vals = frozenset(int(i.rsplit('.',1)[0].lstrip("S")) for i in values)
        if vals in blacklist: continue
        blacklist.add(vals)
        outfile.writerow(title)
        outfile.writerow(values)
```

Comment: This assumes the headers though (they are hardcoded). That might anywhere between a major drawback and absolutely fine. You could be capturing them instread as you parse the file and adding them to the set (which would not be frozen in that case) by using a regex designed for the task

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: could you please expand on your comment. I'm not sure I fully understand your meaning

Comment: a regex is not necessary though. The pattern is not that complicated. A simple `if line.startswith('Part-1-1.'): blacklist.update(line.rstrip().split(','))` should do.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, it still did not work. There are some errors which I removed. outfile=csv.writer(fout) and blacklist is not always same. There can be anyother number after SS . This was just an example.

Comment: @HamadHassan: in that case, please update your original post to include a complete description of what should be in the blacklist. Then I'll be able to update my answer for you

Comment: @inspectorG4dget , I have updated. All the lines having same numbers after SS in both fields should be deleted

Comment: @HamadHassan Do you want unique combinations of the *Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE and Part-1-1 lines? Or do you just want unique Part-1-1 lines?

Comment: @HamadHassan: I think I have a better understanding of your problem. Take a look at the edit and let me know what you think

Comment: @JesseBakker,  *Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE , has to remain but all the other duplicate or triplicate  etc entires need to be deleted along with their OWN  *Contact Pair, interaction=IntPropPrior1, small sliding, type=SURFACE TO SURFACE line which is the line one above them. Clear?